# How can I randomly select a number of cells and display the contents in a message box?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of ID numbers 1101-1137 in cells A1-A37. I would like to click a button to randomly select 20 of these, with no repetitions, and display them in a message box.

What I have right now seems to randomly select from the numbers 1-37, not the actual contents of the cells, and I can't figure out how to fix it. For example, if I delete the number 1137 from cell A37, the number 37 can still end up in the message box; if I replace the number 1105 in cell A5 with the letter E, E will not show up in the message box but 5 can.

However, if I change "Const nItemsTotal As Long = 37" to equal some other number, say 31, it will only output numbers from 1-31.

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const nItemsToPick As Long = 20
Const nItemsTotal As Long = 37

Dim rngList As Range
Dim idx() As Long
Dim varRandomItems() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim booIndexIsUnique As Boolean

Set rngList = Range("A1").Resize(nItemsTotal, 1)

ReDim idx(1 To nItemsToPick)
ReDim varRandomItems(1 To nItemsToPick)
For i = 1 To nItemsToPick
    Do
        booIndexIsUnique = True ' Innocent until proven guilty
        idx(i) = Int(nItemsTotal * Rnd + 1)
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            If idx(i) = idx(j) Then
                ' It's already there.
                booIndexIsUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If booIndexIsUnique = True Then
        strString = strString & vbCrLf & idx(i)
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    varRandomItems(i) = rngList.Cells(idx(i), 1)

  Next i
    Msg = strString
    MsgBox Msg
' varRandomItems now contains nItemsToPick unique random
' items from range rngList.

End Sub
```

I'm sure it's a silly mistake, but I'm lost. Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a little to one line in your code... the line is now:

```
strString = strString & vbCrLf & Cells(idx(i), 1).Value
```

the full code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Const nItemsToPick As Long = 20
Const nItemsTotal As Long = 37

Dim rngList As Range
Dim idx() As Long
Dim varRandomItems() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim booIndexIsUnique As Boolean

Set rngList = Range("A1").Resize(nItemsTotal, 1)

ReDim idx(1 To nItemsToPick)
ReDim varRandomItems(1 To nItemsToPick)
For i = 1 To nItemsToPick
    Do
        booIndexIsUnique = True ' Innocent until proven guilty
        idx(i) = Int(nItemsTotal * Rnd + 1)
        For j = 1 To i - 1
            If idx(i) = idx(j) Then
                ' It's already there.
                booIndexIsUnique = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If booIndexIsUnique = True Then
        strString = strString & vbCrLf & Cells(idx(i), 1).Value
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    varRandomItems(i) = rngList.Cells(idx(i), 1)

  Next i
    Msg = strString
    MsgBox Msg
' varRandomItems now contains nItemsToPick unique random
' items from range rngList.

End Sub
```

So rather than returning the number, it uses the number returned to look at the value on the row that it relates to.

Comment: You are absolutely lovely and of course now it works perfectly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If you construct a string containing the IDs already found through randomization, you can check for repeats.

```
Dim i As Long, msg As String, id As String

msg = Chr(9)
For i = 1 To 20
    id = 1100 + Int((37 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Do Until Not CBool(InStr(1, msg, Chr(9) & id & Chr(9)))
        Debug.Print id & msg
        id = 1100 + Int((37 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    Loop
    msg = msg & id & Chr(9)
Next i
msg = Mid(Left(msg, Len(msg) - 1), 2)

MsgBox msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just shuffle the **indices**:

```
Sub MAIN()
   Dim ary(1 To 37) As Variant
   Dim i As Long, j As Long

   For i = 1 To 37
      ary(i) = i
   Next i

   Call Shuffle(ary)

   msg = ""
   For i = 1 To 20
      j = ary(i)
      msg = msg & vbCrLf & Cells(j, 1).Value
   Next i
   MsgBox msg
End Sub



Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For i = Low To Hi
        Helper(i) = Rnd
    Next i


    j = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While j > 0
        For i = Low To Hi - j
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
            Helper(i + j) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        For i = Hi - j To Low Step -1
          If Helper(i) > Helper(i + j) Then
            tempF = Helper(i)
            Helper(i) = Helper(i + j)
            Helper(i + j) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(i)
            InOut(i) = InOut(i + j)
            InOut(i + j) = Temp
          End If
        Next i
        j = j \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another one approach:

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object, i%
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.comparemode = vbTextCompare
    While Dic.Count <> 20
        i = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 37)
        If Not Dic.exists(i) Then Dic.Add i, Cells(i, "A")
    Wend
    MsgBox Join(Dic.Items, Chr(13))
End Sub
```

test:

---

[image]